# Is there a way using scrapy to export each item that is scraped into a separate json file?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

currently I am using "yield item" after every item i scrape, though it gives me all the items in one single Json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scrapy-pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline-example) and from there you can insert each `item` into seperate files.

I have set a `counter` in my spider so that it increments on each item yield and added that value to `item`. Using that `counter` value I'm creating file names.

**Test_spider.py**

```
class TestSpider(Spider):
    # spider name and all
    file_counter = 0

def parse(self, response):
    # your code here

def parse_item(self, response):
     # your code here
     self.file_counter += 1
      item = Testtem(
        #other items, 
        counter=self.file_counter)
     yield item
```

enable `pipeline` in `settings.py` by

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'test1.pipelines.TestPipeline': 100}
```

**pipelines.py**

```
class TestPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        with open('test_data_%s' % item.get('counter'), 'w') as wr:
            item.pop('counter') # remove the counter data, you don't need this in your item
            wr.write(str(item))
        return item
```